# <b-form-input> in vue.js is not getting modified value when it is tried to save

Tags: vue.js, events

The steps to reproduce is as follows -

1. A row is dynamically generated with  as an input field.
2. Set previously saved values and working fine.
3. Modified the value and changed event is being fired.

Problem: The changed value is not received and an undefined value is being retrieved always.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: <b-form-input> is input control whose value is set dynamically which was saved before

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what issue you are facing but it is working fine in the below code snippet.

By using `@change` event on `<b-form-input>`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    inputText: 'Alpha',
  },
  methods: {
    getUpdatedValue() {
      console.log(this.inputText);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <b-form-input v-model="inputText" @change="getUpdatedValue"></b-form-input>
</div>
```

Comment: In my case, I am getting older value in the changed event. I am using: value and not using v-model. I will try and update it here. Thanks

Comment: Sure. You can try and let me know if you still face the issue. Will try to resolve that.

Comment: The issue is resolved by adding @change method like the followings -<b-form-input v-model="inputText" @change="getUpdatedValue(objectId, $event)"></b-form-input>  where event contains the value of the box. I updated a collection with the modified values and it was saved successfully.

Comment: Thats great! Kindly accept this answer if it helps you. So that it will help other developers as well.